# find always returns "/mnt/hgfs protocol error" (VMware, Debian 8.x)

Tags: filesystems, vmware

I'm using VMware to run Debian 8.x.
Regardless of if something is found or not, the command

```
find / -type d -name [Directory Name]
```

keeps returning

```
find: '/mnt/hgfs': protocol error".
```

[image]

Can someone please help me understand what the command is complaining about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is complaining that while searching your whole filesystem it encountered an error accessing the `/mnt/hgfs` part.

The `/mnt/hgfs` is a place where VMware mounts the "Host-Guest File System" used to share files between the host and guest machines.

Given the information you provided, it's difficult to tell ehy the error occurs. It might be outdated VMware Tools inside the machine or misconfigured share.